# angularjs error message even without touching the field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling

why the following angularjs form throws in the following errors whereas, nothing is typed in the input field, nor clicked on it.

It is throwing in **"It's a valid name!"** and **Error in the field.** at the same time, even without typing or clicking on the field.
Does anyone know the reason?

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.field1.$valid}" >
    <label class="control-label" >
        Name
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="myModel.field1" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20"
           style="" type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Enter the name"/>
    <p class="error text-small block" ng-show="Form.field1.$error.maxlength">Too long!</p>
    <p class="error text-small block" ng-show="Form.field1.$error.minlength">Too short!</p>
    <p class="error text-small block" ng-show="Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$error">Error in the field.</p>
    <p class="success text-small" ng-show="Form.field1.$valid">It's a valid name!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because having a length of 0 is valid for 'ng-minlength'.
If you want 0 to be invalid, you must use 'ng-required'.

My guess is that you want something like the following:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.field1.$valid}">
    <label class="control-label" >
        Name
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="myModel.field1" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20" ng-required="true"
           style="" type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Enter the name"/>
    <p class="error text-small block" ng-show="Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$error.maxlength">Too long!</p>
    <p class="error text-small block" ng-show="Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$error.minlength">Too short!</p>
    <p class="error text-small block" ng-show="Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$error.required">Required!</p>
    <p class="error text-small block" ng-show="Form.field1.$dirty && (Form.field1.$error.maxlength || Form.field1.$error.minlength || Form.field1.$error.required)">Error in the field.</p>
    <p class="success text-small" ng-show="Form.field1.$valid">It's a valid name!</p>
</div>
```